# Is it possible to inverse a direction of property? (about syntax of objective-c)

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible like following inverse direction?

[Normally direction of property]

```
@interface MainClass {
  CustomClass *test1;
 }
 @end

 @implementation MainClass
  self.test1 = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
 @end
```

[Wondering about inverse directrion of property]

Is it possible to indicate from test1 to self?

```
ex) like test1.myowner? or test1<-self? or test1/self or etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. You can't relate from the object that is set to the object of which the proprty is set. You'll almost certainly want to declare a property on `CustomClass` also, then in the setter of `MainClass`, set the property of the instance of `CustomClass` to `self`.

Comment: Thinking about whipping up some Obj-C runtime hackery to cleverly solve this. Would be a real convenience.

Comment: This most often appears in model layer code.   Core Data can manage these kinds of relationships automatically, among many other things.

Answer (score 3):

No, properties are unidirectional. You would have to explicitly define an inverse property and assign to that.

With two objects referencing each other, you also have to be careful not to introduce a retain cycle. Only one of the properties must be retained/strong, otherwise, you end up with two objects that can never be released.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this kind of behavour yourself by implementin the setter method manually for example

```
- (void)setTest1:(CustomClass *)aCustomClass
{
    test1 = aCustomClass;
    test1.myowner = self;
}
```

You will of cause have to add the myowner property to CustomClass and make it weak or unsafe_unretained to avoid a circular retain loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to pick apart here. First of all, pretty much any class that you declare should inherit from `NSObject`.

```
@interface MainClass : NSObject {
```

you should use `@property` and `@synthesize` to create an instance variable, don't allocate an iVar like what you're trying to do. It would better be written as follows:

```
 @interface MainClass : NSObject 
 @property(nonatomic, retain) CustomClass *test1;
 @end

 @implementation MainClass
 @synthesize test1;

 // only if you're not using ARC
 -(void)dealloc {
     [test1 release];
     [super dealloc];
 }

 @end
```

> ex) like test1.myowner? or test1<-self? or test1/self or etc..

all of those are wrong, if you want to access the instance of MainClass from test1, you'll have to declare an instance variable on that class and set "`self`" to that instance variable. It might be a better idea to implement `MainClass` as a singleton if you're only going to have one instance of it.